# Excel 2016 - Replace #N/A with match function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having trouble making it so that instead of blanks or entries that have no existent matches will display **NotHere** instead of #N/A.  I reviewed a lot of other items but haven't gotten it to work.

Using Excel Pro Plus 2016 64bit.

```
=MATCH(D10819,CTX!B:B,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap in IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(D10819,CTX!B:B,0),"NotHere")
```